# How to send WIFI details and other inputs to raspberry using a phone?

Tags: wifi, raspberry-pi-os

I have a raspberry zero W, and would like users to connect to it and setup their own wifi details as well as set some inputs like their city and address and have raspberry use this info for the program code.

For example,

Users would connect to the raspberry and setup their wifi details, so now the raspberry has access to the internet through their wifi

Then the users can input other details such as their names, city etc and raspberry would use this info as variables in the main code

How does one achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Without going too much into details your steps would probably be:

- set-up a WiFi server, either open or with known PSK on the Pi zero (f.e. http://www.penguintutor.com/news/raspberrypi/wireless-hotspot, https://thepi.io/how-to-use-your-raspberry-pi-as-a-wireless-access-point/ etc.)
- use a simple web-server (Dancer-2, Flask, ...) to create a page that asks for the WiFi details and has a "go connect' button.
  (I would start with https://metacpan.org/dist/Dancer2/view/lib/Dancer2/Tutorial.pod , but then I don't like Python)

The user connects to the Pi's webserver, enters the details and presses "go"

- the Pi sets the wifi parameters as entered and disables the Dancer-2/Flask app.
- The Pi connects to the WiFi network ( see f.e. https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruits-raspberry-pi-lesson-3-network-setup/setting-up-wifi-with-occidentalis or https://dullaart.website/raspberry/1_headless_setup.html#a1.3.)
- The Pi starts the web-app for normal operation. (use Dancer-2, Flask or even a full-blown Apache for this)

To make it easier for the user to find the Pi, you may use a `.local` mDNS name and the Avahi deamon. (f.e. https://www.scivision.dev/raspberry-pi-wifi-avahi/ etcetera)

Most steps are worth a complete howto, as you can see.

Comment: Is there an online guide to do any of this? I have basic knowledge in coding and not much in python, it's my first pi. I understand the idea of what you said but have no idea how to implement it

Comment: @NLed: This is a good answer to the question you have asked. But surely you can see that an answer that provided all details for each step would be far too long, detailed and inappropriate for SE. If you have further questions, perhaps you should do a bit of research, followed by trial-and-error? You are not limited to the number of questions you can ask, but they should be [good questions.](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/asking)